# How can I ensure an array is passed a certain number of parameter in a function apart from using a tuple

Tags: typescript

How can I ensure an array is passed a certain number of parameter in a function apart from using a tuple

I have a function in typescript which takes an array as a parameter and when the function is called i want a certain number of elements to be passed in the array how can I achieve this apart from using a tuple

```
type a =(arr: [number, number]) => boolean
const b:a = (arr) => {}
b([]) // should throw an error if the parameter passed in array is less than two
```

How can I achieve this without using tuples

Comment: what's wrong with tuples?

Comment: provide min reproducible example

Comment: Please review the guidelines for [ask] and consider providing a [mre] that would help steer the solution.  Also, can you demonstrate *why* you don't want tuples in your answer?  If I held up a hammer and asked you how to drive nails into a wall *without* using the hammer, you would probably want to know why I've eliminated the most reasonable solution in advance.

Comment: No specific reason i was just wondering if there was another way to do the same thing

Comment: Well, you *should* use a tuple; using `{length: 2, 0: number, 1: number}` is like using a frying pan instead of a hammer to drive in nails.  It will *work*, but it's not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `Array<number>` with a specific length and types for each index:

```
interface TupleOfTwoNumbers extends Array<number> {
    length: 2;
    0: number;
    1: number;
}

type a = (arr: TupleOfTwoNumbers) => boolean

const b: a = (arr) => true

b([]);        // !
b([1]);       // !
b([1, 2]);    // ok
b([1, 2, 3]); // !
```

but the errors generated aren't as helpful:

> Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'TupleOfTwoNumbers'.(2345)

compared to using tuples:

> Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[number, number]'.
> Source has 0 element(s) but target requires 2.(2345)

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0nlDw)

Answer (score 0):

If you *have* to do this instead of using tuples, you can type the `length` property of the array as the length you want, and then it will require the length of the passed array to match that.

```js
type FixedLengthArray<T, Length extends number = number> = readonly T[] & { 
  length: Length
}

function foo(arr: FixedLengthArray<number, 3>) {
  // Do stuff
}

foo([1, 2, 3, 4] as const);
/*
Argument of type 'readonly [1, 2, 3, 4]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FixedLengthArray<number, 3>'.
  Type 'readonly [1, 2, 3, 4]' is not assignable to type '{ length: 3; }'.
    Types of property 'length' are incompatible.
      Type '4' is not assignable to type '3'.ts(2345)
*/
```

The `as const` is required to make the length of the array fixed instead of just plain `number`.
This reflects reality, as a regular array's length can change and therefore type-checking should fail unless it is definitely a certain length.

You can use either `as const` or assert the type of the array:

```js
// as const

const arr1 = [1, 2, 3] as const
foo(arr1)

// Type Assertion

type SetLength<T extends any[], Length extends number> = T & {
  length: Length;
};

const arr2 = [1, 2, 3]
foo(arr as SetLength<typeof arr, 3>)
```